# post file from HDFS using Curl

Tags: hadoop, curl, hdfs

How can I post a file from HDFS using Curl ?

```
curl  --data-binary @/user/file.txt 'http://127.0.0.1/update'
```

this works but now I have put my file in HDFS are they any way to use curl to post the file in hdfs

Answer (score 0):

You can use HDFS REST APIs to do this. Refer [this](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html#Create_and_Write_to_a_File).